# Updated php.ini but php.info shows different values

Tags: php.ini

I've updated `php.ini` using `root` with some value changes in `max time out` and `upload file size` and such, but when I checked `mywebsite.com/info.php` I don't see the changes on what I've edited.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted your Apache server?

Answer (score 3):

You need to restart your apache service.

Either

```
service httpd restart
```

or

```
restart apache
```

depending on you platform/installation mode.